# Show all files in a directory and allow user to upload and delete

Tags: php, file

I want to allow user to upload files to a folder (and delete it too). The page should also be able to show all the files inside.

The show files part has been completed (I've modified it from some sample codes) ,but I have problem in file upload and deleteion

```
<?php

 $dir="./download/";

$files1 = scandir($dir);
$count= count($files1); 
$index=0;
?>

<table border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0>

<tr><td style="background-color:#666666;color:#FFFFFF;">Filename
<td  style="background-color:#666666;color:#FFFFFF;">Delete
<td  style="background-color:#666666;color:#FFFFFF;">View

<? while ($index <$count){

if (!($files1[$index]=="." || $files1[$index]=="..")){ ?> 

<tr><td><?php echo $files1[$index]; ?><td>


<a href="deletefile2.php?filename=<?php  echo $files1[$index]; ?>">Delete</A>

<td>
<a href="./download/<?php echo $files1[$index]; ?>" target=_new>View</a>
<?php
} 

$index++; }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the "Show Files part", you are already correct.

For the deletion part (say in your deletefile2.php), you may use the following codes

```
<?php
$filetodelete=$_REQUEST["filename"]; 
unlink("./download/". $filetodelete);
?>
```

On the other hand, for the file upload, please add the following to the top of your file:

```
<form action=upload1.php method=post 
enctype="multipart/form-data">

Upload: <input type=file name=file1 id=file1>
<br><br><input type=submit value="upload">
<br><br>
</form>
```

after that, create the following upload1.php

```
<?php 

$upload1 ="";

if (isset($_FILES['file1']['name']) && $_FILES['file1']['name'] !="")
{

$upload1 =  $_FILES['file1']['name'];
copy($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'],'./download/'. $upload1);
unlink($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name']);

}
    
?>

<script>
alert("File Uploaded. Thank you");
history.go(-1);
</script>
```